# Can solr contain multi-language stop words in a file?

Tags: solr, multilingual

I have to configure solr to support search in English and Hebrew. I am trying define common data type for both of languages. Can I store Hebrew and English stopwords inside one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is nothing magical about the values in the stopwords file - they're just words, so as long as they words you've entered matches the actual words in the field, it should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you! And one small question: I add some filters to data type but a filter can support only English, for example. What will happen if I put inside row some Hebrew words? Will it be proceed correct?

Comment: That will depend on the hebrew words and the implementation of the filter - Since the character set used for hebrew and english is different I'm guessing you'll be safe.